# How to import and use protobuf timestamppb package in a proto file?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I want to use `timestamppb` package in my `protobufs` because it helps to easily convert `Timestamp` to `Go` `time. Time`. However, I can't figure out how to import it into the `.proto` file. When I try I get the following error `Import "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb" was not found or had errors.`

I looked at the documentation [timestamppb docs](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb) for the `timestamppb` package but it seems there are no examples of how to use it in `.proto` files.

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb";
// import "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb.proto"; I tried this too but no luck

message Example {
  timestamppb.Timestamp example_time = 1;
}
```

Comment: `import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";`
Your link seems to be the import that is used in Go Code itself not the one for protos definition

Comment: Thanks! It was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Alright I put it into a brief answer.

Answer (score 3):

The import for `.proto` files is:

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
```

The one that you tried is the path that is needed in Go Code in combination with `go get`.